Status 400 when returning to Studio from function
In Twilio Studio I am using a TwiML Redirect to call this function:
forward_call function
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  const num = twiml.dial();
  num.number({
    url: '/agent_screen_call'
  }, '6137451576');
  return callback(null, twiml);
};

agent_screen_call function
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  const gather = twiml.gather({
    input: 'dtmf',
    numDigits: 1,
    method: 'GET',
    action: 'https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/XXXX~~my_account~~XXXX/Flows/XXXX~~my_flow_id~~XXXX?FlowEvent=return',
    actionOnEmptyResult: 'true'
  });
  gather.say("You have a call on the business line!");
  gather.say('Press 1 to talk with the caller or 2 to send caller to voicemail or 3 to redirect caller to the National Call Centre');
  return callback(null, twiml);
};

The call keeps ending with an error whenever the agent selects a number. It ends with this error...
Msg
Got HTTP 400 response to https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/XXXX~~my_account~~XXXX/Flows/XXXX~~my_flow_id~~XXXX
ErrorCode
11200
LogLevel
ERROR


I hope this will help to resolve the error. 
As this is error 400. There is nothing wrong with your code. But, it is missing something like response.redirect. 

if(event.Digits === 1) {
 response.say("Connecting you to the caller");

}else if..............
twiml.redirect(`/${redirectUrl}`);

OR using node/express.js

app.post("/redirect", async(req, res)=>{
 const digit = req.body.Digits;
 if(digit === '1'){
 const state = req.body.callerState;
 const stateId = await models.findOne(state);
return res.redirect(`/call/redirect/${stateid}`);
 }
})

Please refer
Ref => https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/call-forwarding-nodejs-express
